# D3 bar chart sorting - axis label sorting logic explanation needed

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I've build bar chart with sorting on click: https://codepen.io/wawraf/pen/gvpXWm. It's based on Mike Bostock's chart https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705.

It works fine, but when I tried to build it from scratch I realized there is something i do not fully understand: Line 72 contains following function:

```
var x0 = scaleX
  .domain(data.sort(sort(direction))
  .map(function(d) { return d[0]; }));
```

So it's using variable scaleX defined before (Line 16), but when instead of "scaleX" variable I want to use raw d3 reference (which is actually the same as scaleX):

```
var x0 = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width - margin * 2])
   .domain(data.sort(sort(direction))
   .map(function(d) { return d[0]; }));
```

axis sorting ("g" elements) doesn't work.

I would be glad if anyone could explain why it doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do...

```
var x0 = scaleX.domain(data.sort(sort(direction)).map(function(d) {
    return d[0];
}));
```

... you are not only setting a new variable `x0`, but **changing the scaleX** domain as well. As the axis is based on `scaleX`, not `x0`, it won't do the transition in your second case, which only sets `x0` (without changing `scaleX`).

You can certainly do:

```
var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width - margin * 2])
    .domain(data.sort(sort(direction))
        .map(function(d) {
            return d[0];
        }));
```

As long as you change the axis' scale:

```
xAxis.scale(x0);
```

here is the updated CodePen with those changes: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQveBy?editors=0010